# Need a function to return date of next/Previous business day SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need help creating a sql server (2012) function that when given the following variables

```
Monday    True/False
Tuesday   True/False
Wednesday True/False
Thursday  True/False
Friday    True/False
Saturday  True/False
Sunday    True/False
Date1     mm/dd/yyyy
Type      Next/Previous
```

it will return the date of the next (or previous) business day for Date1

So for example if Date1 is 12/22/2014 (Monday), and passing the parameters below, it would return 12/26/2014 (Friday)

```
Monday    True
Tuesday   False
Wednesday False
Thursday  False
Friday    True
Saturday  True
Sunday    True
Date1     12/22/2014
Type      Next
```

Comment: Could you clearify what you whant to achieve?

Comment: find either next or previous business (working day) given a basic list of working/off days and a specific date (typically today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `table type variable` first:

```
CREATE TYPE BusinessDateTableType AS TABLE 
( 
   [WeekDay] VARCHAR(50),
   IsBusinessDate BIT 
);
```

Then create the function that takes a table-valued parameter of the above type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_GetNextBusinessDay
(    
    @businessDates BusinessDateTableType READONLY, 
    @type VARCHAR(10),
    @day DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @nextBusinessDate DATE

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @type = 'Next' THEN 1 
                WHEN @type = 'Previous' THEN -1
               END AS i
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @type = 'Next' THEN i + 1 
                WHEN @type = 'Previous' THEN i -1
               END AS i
        FROM cte
        WHERE ABS(i) < 7
    )                                                                 
    SELECT TOP 1 @nextBusinessDate = DATEADD(day, i, @day)
    FROM cte AS d1
    INNER JOIN @businessDates AS d2 ON DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(day, i, @day)) = d2.WeekDay
    WHERE d2.IsBusinessDate = 1           
    ORDER BY ABS(i)                  

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @nextBusinessDate
END
```

**EDIT:**

We can easily substitute the table-type variable in the UDF with seven `BIT` type variables, then use a `table variable` inside the UDF and populate it with the values of these variables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_GetNextBusinessDay2
(    
    @IsMonWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsTueWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsWedWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsThuWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsFriWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsSatWorkingDay BIT,
    @IsSunWorkingDay BIT,
    @type VARCHAR(10),
    @day DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @nextBusinessDate DATE

    DECLARE @businessDates TABLE ([WeekDay] VARCHAR(50), IsBusinessDate BIT) 

    INSERT INTO @businessDates VALUES
    ('Monday', @IsMonWorkingDay),
    ('Tuesday', @IsTueWorkingDay),
    ('Wednesday', @IsWedWorkingDay),
    ('Thursday', @IsThuWorkingDay),
    ('Friday', @IsFriWorkingDay),
    ('Saturday', @IsSatWorkingDay),
    ('Sunday', @IsSunWorkingDay)

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @type = 'Next' THEN 1 
                WHEN @type = 'Previous' THEN -1
               END AS i
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @type = 'Next' THEN i + 1 
                WHEN @type = 'Previous' THEN i -1
               END AS i
        FROM cte
        WHERE ABS(i) < 7
    )                                                                 
    SELECT TOP 1 @nextBusinessDate = DATEADD(day, i, @day)
    FROM cte AS d1
    INNER JOIN @businessDates AS d2 ON DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(day, i, @day)) = d2.WeekDay
    WHERE d2.IsBusinessDate = 1           
    ORDER BY ABS(i)                  

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @nextBusinessDate
END
```

Using the second version of the UDF with this test data:

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10) = 'Next'
DECLARE @day DATE = '2014-12-22'
DECLARE @nextBusinessDate DATE

SET @nextBusinessDate = dbo.UDF_GetNextBusinessDay2(1,0,0,0,0,0,1, @type, @day)
SELECT @nextBusinessDate
```

produces the following result:

```
2014-12-28
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating a table.

Comment: @Bill This is not a table, BusinessDateTableType is a *Table Type*. It is the most elegant way to pass the **working days info** into the function.

Comment: @Bill otherwise you have to provide *14 additional variables* to your function, then declare a table variable inside the function and populate the table variable using the values of the 14 additional variables

Comment: Thanks, Problem becomes having to maintain that table instead of having the flexibility of just passing days values

Comment: @Bill I have edited the answer to include a second version of the UDF using separate variables for each day of the week. It is tested for both *Previous* and *Next* types and works OK.

Answer (score 2):

The following query calculates the next valid "day" after any given day of the week.  And it calculates the number of days to that day.

```
with days as (
      select 1 as dow, 'Monday' as name, @Monday as flag union all
      select 2, 'Tuesday', @Tuesday union all
      select 3, 'Wednesday', @Wednesday union all
      select 4, 'Thursday', @Thursday union all
      select 5, 'Friday', @Friday union all
      select 6, 'Saturday', @Saturday union all
      select 7, 'Sunday', @Sunday
     )
select d.*, d2.dow as next_dow,
       (case when d2.dow > d.dow then d2.dow - d.dow else d2.dow - d.dow + 7 end) as days_to_next
 from days d cross apply
      (select top 1 d2.dow
       from days d2
       where d2.flag = 'true'
       order by (case when d2.dow > d.dow then 1 else 2 end), d2.dow
      )  d2;
```

The next step is just to lookup the day you want:

```
with days as (
      select 1 as dow, 'Monday' as name, @Monday as flag union all
      select 2, 'Tuesday', @Tuesday union all
      select 3, 'Wednesday', @Wednesday union all
      select 4, 'Thursday', @Thursday union all
      select 5, 'Friday', @Friday union all
      select 6, 'Saturday', @Saturday union all
      select 7, 'Sunday', @Sunday
     )
select dateadd(day, 
               (case when d2.dow > d.dow then d2.dow - d.dow else d2.dow - d.dow + 7 end),
               @Date1
              )
 from days d cross apply
      (select top 1 d2.dow
       from days d2
       where d2.flag = 'true'
       order by (case when d2.dow > d.dow then 1 else 2 end), d2.dow
      )  d2
where d.dow = datename(weekday, @Date1);
```

Of course, `datename()` could return non-English names if with non-English internationalization settings.  The query could be adjusted if that logic doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me with making it a function? Also, I made an edit to pass Type parameter for next/previous after you answered.

Answer (score 1):

This code gets the next or previous business day by creating a list of three dates starting from the start date. If we want the previous business day then we get the biggest date if we want the next business day we get the smallest date.


`DECLARE @direction AS INT =1 
--If direction is  1 you get the next business day.
--If direction is -1 you get the previous business day. 

DECLARE @startDate AS DATE ='2017-07-21'

SELECT CASE @direction WHEN 1 THEN MIN(listOfDays.d) ELSE MAX(listOfDays.d) END AS nextBusinessDay FROM(
(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Number*@direction,@startDate)AS d FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) AS Numbers(Number) )) listOfDays
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,listOfDays.d) NOT IN (1,7)`

Comment: please add some description to answer Please.

Comment: Assuming this provides the desired output, this looks a lot nicer than the accepted answer. Is it a case of newer versions having new capabilities that made it simpler to write?

Answer (score 0):

The following code selects from a list of days the next business day excluding weekends and non working dates.

**REQUIREMENTS**: In order for the following code to work a Numbers table must exist as well as a  Non_working_dates table.

The Numbers table should have at least one field. The field name must be Number. The field must not accept duplicates. The data type must be INT.

The Non_working_days table must have as least one field. The field name must be Non_working_date. The field must accept no duplicate values. The data type must be DATE without time.

```
DECLARE @startDate AS DATE = '2017-07-03'
--Step 2. Get the next business day.
 SELECT TOP 1 listOfDates.d AS nextBusinessDay  FROM
   (
   --Step 1. Get a month's worth of dates. 
     The dates must not be weekend days or non working days.
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Number,@startDate)AS d FROM Numbers WHERE Number < 30
     ) listOfDates
     WHERE   listOfDates.d> @startDate  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,listofdates.d) NOT IN (1,7)
     AND listOfDates.d NOT IN (SELECT Non_working_date FROM Non_working_dates WHERE Non_working_date>=@startDate)
     ORDER BY listOfDates.d ASC
```